# How to add animated (html+css) text to HomeSlider images in Prestashop

Tags: html, css, prestashop

I want to add some animated text (HTML&CSS based) on HomeSlider images. I have tried this by adding html code to description field in HomeSlider module configuration and placed the css code in homeslider.css file but the animation text is nowhere showing. How to achive this correctly?

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you disable the cache in the performance settings? Are you edited the CSS code in your theme or in the module?

Comment: @rufein yes i have cleared the cache after saving settings but text nowhere shows on images.

Answer (score 0):

Try disable Html purifier option,also see that your html code to not be more that 4000 characters.If still not working try edit file HomeSlide.php in line description change isCleanHtml with isString >> Save and reset module.